# adding a class to main, using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

So I am using Netbeans for the first time and am having issues creating multiple classes and running them under my main method under the same project directory.  For instance, I am working through chapter 1 of a book, and would like to keep all my methods/classes under this directory.  However, I am running into issues because one class already is using the "main" method argument, so I am having difficulty calling my independent classes.

Here is two independent classes that I am sure compile, yet I need another script that calls them separately.

Below is function 1.

```
package chapter1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 ** @author anthonycolombo60*/
public class Chapter1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations!");

}
   }
```

How do I add a simple "HI" command that is called from the main?

```
package chapter1;
 *
 * @author anthonycolombo60
*/
 public class Chapter1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hi!");
}

}
```

Appreciate any tips.

Comment: You can't have two classes called Chapter1 in the same package (chapter1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have multiple classes in the same .java file. Each class can have their own main method.

To call/run the main of another class simply create an object of that class.

```
//Lesson1.java
//If you place a public here, the class name must follow the Java file name
public class Lesson1      
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myMethod();  //Call MyClass's method
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public void myMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

If you want to call MyClass's main, go to `properties` of your current project -> `Run` -> `Main Class`, set to the class you want.

**If you have your classes written in separate .java files.**
You can just run a specific class in your project by going to Netbeans `menu bar` -> `Run` -> `Run File (Shift F6)` 
 It will only run the class instead of the main method of your first created java class.